# Is possible to keyframe a mask textures as a factor for two other textures in realtime?

Tags: texturing, 3d-view, opengl

Is possible to keyframe a mask textures as a factor for two other textures in realtime? I have set up a blender internal materials node setup, basically two distinct materials mixed with a *Mix RGB Node*.

I then have a mask applied as the factor. When I move the coordinates manually in the mapping node for the mask, the mask moves nicely separating the  materials in realtime, however, when I keyframe the  values, it doesn't work at all. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You must be doing something wrong. If you make 2 material and a mask texture, then make a third material that blends the 2 materials using the Mix Color node with the texture as the Fac input the mask should be applied correctly.
Between the UV output of the Geometry node and the Vector input of the Texture node add a Mapping node. That node has support for adding keyframes to any value.
What you want is to add keyframes to the location value and animate the value over multiple frames.
I tested it and it work, here is the file:

[image]

Comment: to ask for clarification and information please use the comment section. Also, links in pasteall.org are good only for a short period of time, once the link goes down this answer will make no sense unless there is some text that explains what the proposed answer is. Think of links and images as supporting material for a written answer. For permanent hosting for blend files please use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know about that site.